# Changing font size inside iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have iFrame like this:

```
<iframe id="iFrame" name="iframe" src=""></iframe>
```

Source is entered through url. I need to change the text size of content inside this iFrame. Both iFrame and the source url are on same domain. I tried this:

```
function setFontSize(fontsize) {
    $('iFrame').contents().css('font-size', '5px');
    alert("i am here");
}

and this


function setFontSize(fontsize) {
    $("#iFrame").css("font-size","5px");
}
```

both seem to not work.

Comment: Is the Iframe page on the same domain as yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#site.html
<iframe id="iFrame" name="iframe" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function($) {
      $(function() {
          var iframe = top.frames['iframe'].document;
          $('p', iframe).css('font-size','5px');
      });
})(jQuery);
</script>

#iframe.html
<p>some test content</p>
```

The clue here is, that it won't work on Your desktop. You need to test it on Your server.
If You copy both files to `/path/to/your/server/root/test` and view `http://localhost/test` You will see the result. 
One more thing: working with iframes is a really restrictive task both sites (parent and iframe) need to be on the same server (same protocol, host, port).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document.getElementById('IFrameName').contentWindow.document.body).find('font').attr("face", "Tahoma")
```